# creating a structure within a structure from imported text files in matlab

Tags: matlab, structure, cell

I'm not sure if anyone can help with this question but here we go. I have 4 folders where each folder contains data for different locations, within the folders I have 8 .txt files which represent the measured variables at each location (i.e. same variables measured in each location). I'm trying to import these into matlab and list the measured variables in astructure so they can be compared and plotted against one another afterwards (without doing this they will over write one another).

I've written a script for importing these into matlab, the script works but not exactly in the way I want it to, the script is as follows:

```
clear all
pathName = 'E:\University\CEH Lancaster\Project\LA practice\final files';
FolderListing = dir(pathName);  
FolderListing = FolderListing(3:end);
    %lists the folder in the directory specified by pathName
for i = 1:length(FolderListing);
    LName{i} = (FolderListing(i).name);
        %obtains the name of each folder
end

for i = 1:length(LName)
    TopFolder{i} = fullfile(pathName,LName{i});
        %path for each individual folder 
    dirListing{i} = dir(fullfile(TopFolder{i},'*.txt'));  
        %list of the .txt files
    for ii = 1:length(dirListing{1,1});
        fileToRead1{1,i}{ii,1} = (dirListing{1,i}(ii,1).name);
        %name of the .txt files in the TopFolder
    end
end

for i = 1:length(fileToRead1);
    for ii = 1:length(fileToRead1{1});
    fid{1,i}{ii,1} = fopen((fullfile(TopFolder{1,i},fileToRead1{1,i}{ii,1})));
        %open the files specified by fileToRead prior to importing the data
        %into matlab
    data{1,i}{ii,1} = textscan(fid{1,i}{ii,1},'%f');
        %import the data into matlab
    [~,name{1,i}{ii,1}] = fileparts(fileToRead1{1,i}{ii,1});
        %obtain the name of each of the variables
    Location.(LName{i}).(genvarname(name{1,i}{ii,1})) = data{1,i}{ii,1};
        %create a strucutre for the individual locations and the
        %variables.
    end
end
```

The problem lies in the final outcome where instead of having Location.Name and then the list of variables, I have Location.Name.variables, which doesn't seem necessary. I realise that its due to the way I've written the last line of the script but I can't seem to change it without it producing an error. Any advice you could give on the problem or on the script in general would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand which format you would prefer. Is it that you have `Location.Alaska.temp = 1;Location.Alaska.lat = 5;Location.Alaska.lon = 3;` and you would prefer to have `Location.Alaska = [1 3 5]`?

Comment: at the moment I have say Location.Alaska.temp{1,1} where instead I would prefer temp to not be a 1x1 cell but just the values. For example, currently if I write Location.Alaska.temp into the command window, matlab returns [365x1 double], instead I would like it to return the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think cell2mat is the function you want for this purpose. Here's my usage, see if it fits your needs:

```
tt = {ones(1,100)};
tt
tt = 

    [1x100 double]
cell2mat(tt)
    ans =

      Columns 1 through 15

         1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1...
```